# Alternatives to "In the grand scheme of things"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for alternatives to *"...in the grand scheme of things."*- either phrases or words, but no full sentences, because I want something I can embed at the end of another sentence.

What could I say instead of: *It didn't really matter **in the grand scheme of things***.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

overall  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/overall)

> - From one end to the other: the overall length of the house.
> - Including everything; comprehensive: the overall costs of medical care.
> - Regarded as a whole; general: My overall impression was favorable.
> - adv. (ō′vər-ôl′) On the whole; generally

As in:

> It didn't really matter **overall**.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

1. **at the end of the day**

PHRASE

You say at the end of the day when you are talking about what happens after a long series of events or what appears to be the case after you have considered the relevant facts.

[informal]

At the end of the day it's up to the Germans to decide.
At the end of the day, the board's not going to be concerned with three or four more dollars.

2. **all things considered**

PHRASE

You say all things considered to indicate that you are making a judgment after taking all the facts into account.
All things considered, I think you have behaved marvelously in coming here.

3. **when all was said and done**

when everything is taken into account (used to indicate that one is making a generalized judgment about a situation).

*either that, or* you can opt for a simple adverb(and start the sentence with it followed by a comma)

1. **ultimately**

ADVERB

Ultimately means finally, after a long and often complicated series of events.
Whatever the scientists ultimately conclude, all of their data will immediately be disputed.

2. **eventually**

in the end, especially after a long delay, dispute, or series of problems.
"eventually, after midnight, I arrived at the hotel"

Examples and definitions - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/ and oxford languages(google)